# Dough, paste, or pastry?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

I'm a bit confused here. Could you help me to differentiate between the meanings of these words?

Comment: Referring to the "uncooked" substance, ***dough*** usually has no sugar or butter/fat/oil (or at least, much less than ***pastry***). Mostly people don't use the word ***paste*** in domestic cooking contexts - it's a bit reminiscent of what goes into [MRM sausages](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/health/1482140.stm). *Meat paste?* Ugh!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The expectation at this and other StackExchange sites is that you have done some preliminary research before asking. What do the dictionaries say? What do your web searches turn up? I encourage you to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Dough** is uncooked, it is malleable and often contains raising agents, or yeast in order for it to rise and bake in the oven. Dough is essential for making breads and pizzas.

[image]

**Pastry** usually refers to small cakes, it can also be the base for pies, tarts, quiches and flans. Pastry doesn't normally contain yeast. Once the raw pastry is baked, it is still called pastry.

**Paste** is a creamy thick mixture, very often found in tubes. Think, toothpaste, or tomato paste. You can make paste with flour and water, and it will have a sticky almost runny texture.

In the comment section the Op asks:

> There's only one question left. Is paste still in use to refer to the
>   raw material of cookies, cakes, breads or pastries to be baked? Or I
>   should stick with dough or batter?

[image]

The raw mixed ingredients for cookies and biscuits in general is usually described a ***creamed mixture***, it is not a *dough* because cookie recipes require butter, eggs and sugar to be amalgamated until they form a creamy-like texture. Yeast is not usually added, but some cooks like adding a pinch of baking powder.

**Batter** is much more liquid looking. It is a mixture of flour, egg(s) and milk, batter is used for making puddings and pancakes; or to coat foods before deep-frying.

Answer (score 3):

*Dough* comes by way of Germanic **daigoz* from [the PIE root ****dheigh-***](http://web.archive.org/web/20080625115651/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE95.html) 'to form (with clay)'.
And anything like clay that can be worked with the hands, usually in preparation for baking,
is *dough*.  Generally, it's made from flour and water, which can form a paste.

*Paste* and *pastry* both come from an ancient Greek word for barley porridge. More cooking.
The use of flour and water as a cheap adhesive dates from the origin of milling and baking.
Hence the verb *paste*.

Finally, a paste is a kind of *glue*. This word comes from Late Latin *gluten*, meaning 'glue'.
Short etymology here, but *gluten* is indeed the sticky part of the wheat kernel.
So all of these are terms ultimately derived from grain cultivation. For food and other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Pastry is a generic term for certain kinds of baked products, typically sweet ones.

Paste is either a description of the consistency of the material ("mix powder and liquid until they form a paste"), or is an adhesive. "Library paste" used to be a flour-and-water mixture, which may be why the terms are cognates of each other.

Dough is usually an uncooked flour-and-whatever mixture that (usually) will be baked. Occasionally, as with paste, it is used by analogy to describe the consistancy of the material even if it isn't edible and/or won't be baked.

Comment: Ok, so paste means _glue_ or any substance that is _creamy_? Paste does not mean liquid substance to be baked then? Only dough? I mean dough is relatively stiff (as it is kneaded), at least in my interpretation. How about pancakes? Do you call its mixture a paste or a dough before frying it in a pan?

Comment: A thin dough, as for pancakes, is usually called a batter. Pastes (when not referring to glue) are usually thicker, but I can't give you an exact range.

Comment: There's only one question left. Is _paste_ still in use to refer to the raw material of cookies, cakes, breads or pastries to be baked? Or I should stick with _dough_ or _batter_ (the former for the thick, the latter for the thin ones)?

Comment: Properly, they are doughs or batters. Many things that are pastes in consistency are not food -- wall patching compound could be described as a paste, for example. Obviously, so can toothpaste. So while the term can be applied to some foodstuffs, it's a descriptive (like gel or liquid), and thus is less informative unless you are specifically trying to describe the texture/thickness of the substance. "Still the icing until it melds into a smooth paste, then apply to the cake."